# How to get a list of member names from Enum?

Tags: c#, enums

This should be fairly simple question. I'm using DocX library to create new word documents. I wanted to make a test word document to see how each TableDesign (enum) looks like to choose the one I need.

> Designs\Styles that can be applied to a table. 
>   Namespace:  Novacode
>   Assembly:  DocX (in DocX.dll) Version: 1.0.0.10 (1.0.0.10)
>
> Syntax:
>
> public enum TableDesign
>
> **Member name**
>    Custom
>    TableNormal
>    TableGrid
>    LightShading
>    LightShadingAccent1
>    ....

And so on. I would like to get a list of those TableDesign's so i could reuse it in a method creating new table with new design for all possibilities, but I don't really know how to get the list from that enum:

```
foreach (var test in TableDesign) {
      createTable(documentWord, test);
}
```

How do I get that?

Comment: As an aside, if you are trying to display `enum` names to the user, you should consider decorating them with attributes (e.g. `DescriptionAttribute`).  It strikes me as a poor habit to directly display variable names to your user.

Comment: In the general case, I see little harm in displaying enum value names to the user, especially names conforming to the C# naming standards (CamelCase). The integer values corresponding to those names are probably not a good idea to display, and full information based on the enum value would probably be preferable, but I don't see harm in it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found answer myself:

```cs
// get a list of member names from Volume enum,
// figure out the numeric value, and display
foreach (string volume in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Volume)))
{
    var value = (byte)Enum.Parse(typeof(Volume), volume);
    Console.WriteLine("Volume Member: {0}\n Value: {1}", volume, value);
}
```

For my specific case I've used:

```cs
foreach (var test in Enum.GetNames(typeof(TableDesign)))
{
  testMethod(documentWord, test);
}
```

and in testMethod I've:

```
tableTest.Design = (TableDesign) Enum.Parse(typeof(TableDesign), test);
```

It worked without a problem (even if it was slow, but I just wanted to get things quickly (and being onetimer performance didn't matter).

Maybe it will help someone in future too :-)

Comment: If the enum consists of sequential values with a known start and stop, it would be simpler to just loop on the enum (or an int equivalent thereof). The above method is *slow*.

Comment: I've updated the post to actually what I've used. It was copy paste from different source that gave me a head start how it should be used (more or less). Didn't need the performance. One time use only :-)

Answer (score 5):

Alternately:

```
foreach (var volume in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Volume))) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Volume Member: {0}\n Value: {1}", 
        volume, (int) volume); 
}
```

`GetValue` will return an `Volume[]` of the values as `enum`s.  Printing an `enum` value will call its `ToString()`, rendering it by it name. Casting to `int` (better than `byte`) will give its number.

Comment: @Yuriy: As much fun as it is to correct Americans on their English, I edited it to remove those errors, so you might as well remove your comment. :-)

Comment: Yes, this is faster and somewhat less convoluted. I still wouldn't call it fast, though.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment on MadBoy's answer, dont know why i cant...
anyway like he said thats the way to go

```cs
foreach (TableDesign t in Enum.GetNames(typeof(TableDesign)))
{
     // do work
}
```

also i think the testing could be like

```cs
bool defined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TableDesign), value);
```

it just seems more natural
last, about the performance issue, i think enums tend to be very small so i wont be worried at all